# Check if the captions option is on

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to know if it is possible to detect if the caption option is activated on the device

I have the code to launch an intent to the captions option but I need to do it only when it has this option turned off

Comment: What is "the caption option"?

Comment: On Settings>Accesibility>Captions